# Arranging numbers 1 to n

Tags: combinatorics

- In how many different ways can you arrange the numbers $1$ to $n$?

My answer would be $n!$.

Comment: @Integrator, will do!

Answer (score 0):

You can take the group $1,2,3$ as one object, which is different from the others. Therefore there are $(n-2)!$ such arrangements.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I reasoned I had $n$ options for the first number all the way down to $(n-3)$, but of course I only have $(n-2)$ options to start with. Huge thanks!